# Kubernetes環境のコンテナ内でSystemctlコマンドを使う方法

Tags: docker, kubernetes

お世話になっております。

Kubernetesで管理しているPod内のコンテナで、Systemctlコマンドを使いたいのですが、
以下のように拒否されてしまいます。

```
# systemctl
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

Dockerコマンドと同様に、--privilegedオプションのようなものをつけて対処することはできないのでしょうか。
現在はMasterと複数のノードを使用して環境を構築している状態で、ノードにログインして、直接Docokerコマンドを打ち、対象のコンテナに対して--privilegedオプションをつけた状態で以下のコマンドを実行しましたが、同様のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
sudo docker exec -it --privileged　コンテナ名　/bin/bash

# systemctl
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

やりたいこととしては、
Deploymentとして作成したCentos内にnginxを入れて、外からServiceにCurlを行い、コンテナを潰すなどして、オートヒーリングなどの機能を試したいのです。
最初からNginxなどのコンテナを立てればよいのですが、他のコマンド等を使用したいため、CentOS環境にNginxを入れ、確認がしたいのです。

どうか、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

お使いのコンテナが systemd を使うようにはセットアップされていないのでしょう。
`docker.io/centos/systemd` を pull して `/usr/sbin/init` を起動するようにして使うといいと思います。

(参考) https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます。
PullしてPod作成まではできたものの、 /usr/sbin/ini　で起動しようとするとエラーとなってしまいました…
起動時のコマンドは
``` kubectl exec -it "コンテナ名" -it -- /usr/sbin/init ```
エラーは以下のようになっております。
``` Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn.
command terminated with exit code 1 ```

検索してみましたが、Dockerでの対処法が多く、解決には至りませんでした

Answer (score 0):

> Deploymentとして作成したCentos内にnginxを入れて、外からServiceにCurlを行い、コンテナを潰すなどして、オートヒーリングなどの機能を試したいのです。

この場合、kubectl delete podやkubectl proxy svc/your-serviceをした上で手元でcurlなどを行えば同様のことが実現できるように思いますが、それだとだめでしょうか？